# Drupal assign taxonomy to content( story )

Tags: drupal, drupal-taxonomy

I have a Druapl application in which the taxonomy is supposed to have 4 nested terms for eg

Sports->World->Country, so when we create a story the taxonomy option is displayed as multiple select box with values nested inside.

Like this:

Sports
--World
---United States
---United Kingdom
---Germany
---France
---So on

So when creating content it will be a huge task for the user to pick one from the enormous list. Is there any way I can split the select box in to 3 where selecting the first level load the second level in another select box and so on.

Or where should I customize ( the files which displays this select box ) this select box.

Any help highly appreciable

Thanks and Regards

Answer (score 1):

Check out Hierarchical Select module - http://drupal.org/project/hierarchical_select